# javascript json jquery cant get custom attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I cant figure out where am I wrong I've been trying so many possibilities and answers found on SO but it just doesn't give me the value of the custom attribute "attr-pid"

```
<div class="prod-col et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4" style="">

<div attr-pid="2" class="bbb_prov product_select et_pb_column et_pb_column_2_4 model_container">
<div class="icon" attr-pid="2"><img src=" " style=" max-width: 100px;"</div></div>

<div attr-pid="4" class="bbb_prov product_select et_pb_column et_pb_column_2_4 model_container">
<div class="icon" attr-pid="4"><img src=" " style=" max-width: 100px;"></div></div>

</div>
```

I have this

```
aProvider = $(".bbb_prov");

if ( me.savedJSON.providersToVisit == undefined ) 
{
    me.savedJSON.providersToVisit = [];
}

for( var y = 0 ; y < aProvider.length ; y++ ) 
{
    me.savedJSON.providersToVisit.push("&bxb_provider_id="+$(aProvider[y]).attr('attr-pid'));   
}

CEF_SaveDataJSON( me.savedJSON );   

console.log(JSON.stringify(me.savedJSON, null, 2));
```

This works on my other div where i have only one class but here where its multiple, console.log just shows me:

```
  "providersToVisit": []
```

Comment: `aProvider` is a jquery collection. I'm not sure that you can access them using array notation.

Comment: @Santi, when you use `[]` accessor on jQuery object it will be the underlying object, so in this instance it will be the actual DOM element. Though they could use [`.eq(y)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead to get the jQuery wrapped element at that position, or just use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through the collection.

Comment: Yes, you are correct Patrick, I just redacted my comment. I went into JSFiddle to investigate my suspicions and found the same thing! Thanks.

Comment: Code work's as shown: https://jsfiddle.net/9xccn2sf/ you might want to to provide a reproducible example showing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works as provided (see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ta3sgh8e/)

HTML

```
<div class="prod-col et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4" style="">
<div attr-pid="2" class="bbb_prov product_select et_pb_column et_pb_column_2_4 model_container">
<div class="icon" attr-pid="2"><img src=" " style=" max-width: 100px;"></div></div>
<div attr-pid="4" class="bbb_prov product_select et_pb_column et_pb_column_2_4 model_container">
<div class="icon" attr-pid="4"><img src=" " style=" max-width: 100px;"></div></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function CEF_SaveDataJSON(data){
  //What happens in this function?
    //data.providersToVisit = [];
}
me = {savedJSON:{}};
aProvider = $(".bbb_prov");
if ( me.savedJSON.providersToVisit == undefined ) 
{
    me.savedJSON.providersToVisit = [];
}
for( var y = 0 ; y < aProvider.length ; y++ ) 
{
  me.savedJSON.providersToVisit.push("&bxb_provider_id="+$(aProvider[y]).attr('attr-pid'));   
}
CEF_SaveDataJSON(me.savedJSON);
console.log(JSON.stringify(me.savedJSON, null, 2));
```

My suspicion is that data is modified inside the `CEF_SaveDataJSON` function prior to your console log, unless there are other shenanigans we can't see which you've excluded from your example.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle http://jsbin.com/kutudogopo/edit?html,js,console

Try this. Since you're just looping through them all anyway you can use JQuery's `.each` method to loop through them.

HTML:

```
  <div class="prod-col et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4" style="">

<div attr-pid="2" class="bbb_prov product_select et_pb_column et_pb_column_2_4 model_container">
<div class="icon" attr-pid="2"><img src=" " style=" max-width: 100px;"</div></div>

<div attr-pid="4" class="bbb_prov product_select et_pb_column et_pb_column_2_4 model_container">
<div class="icon" attr-pid="4"><img src=" " style=" max-width: 100px;"></div></div>
```

JQuery:

```
var aProvider = $(".bbb_prov");
console.log(aProvider.length);

$.each(aProvider, function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  console.log($this.attr('attr-pid'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works as it is, so i found my mistake and my bad for not posting the whole code i really believed the problem was on the code i posted. So I just removed the "if url === "

```
this.onPageLoad = function () 
{
    var url = window.location.href;
    var aModels;
    var aProvider;

    //iphone
    if ( url == "http://blablabla.com/apple/?menuf_id=1" ) //This is were i screwed up and had to remove it.
    {   
        aModels = $(".bbb_prov");


        if ( me.savedJSON.modelsToVisit == undefined ) {
            me.savedJSON.modelsToVisit = [];
        }

        if ( me.savedJSON.phoneModel == undefined ) {
            me.savedJSON.phoneModel = [];
        }

        for( var i = 0 ; i < aModels.length ; i++ ) 
        {
            me.savedJSON.modelsToVisit.push("http://blablabla.com/apple/?menuf_id=1&bxb_model_id="+$(aModels[i]).attr('attr-mid')); 
        }

        for( var x = 0 ; x < aModels.length ; x++ ) 
        {
            me.savedJSON.phoneModel.push($(aModels[x]).text());
        }

        CEF_SaveDataJSON( me.savedJSON );   


        me.blablabla_GotoNextModel();

        aProvider = $(".bbb_prov");

        if ( me.savedJSON.providersToVisit == undefined ) {
            me.savedJSON.providersToVisit = [];
        }


        for( var y = 0 ; y < aProvider.length ; y++ ) 
        {
            me.savedJSON.providersToVisit.push("&bxb_provider_id="+$(aProvider[y]).attr('attr-pid'));   
        }

        CEF_SaveDataJSON( me.savedJSON );   

        console.log(JSON.stringify(me.savedJSON, null, 3));
    }

}
```